# Getting a C++ segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm in a linux server and when I try to execute the program it's returning a segmentation fault. when i use gdb to try and find out why, it returns..

```
Starting program: /home/cups/k

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000401128 in search(int) ()
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.x86_64 libgcc-4.4.7-17.el6.x86_64 libstdc++-4.4.7-17.el6.x86_64
```

I couldn't quite interpret this. In my program i have a function called "search()" but i don't see anything that would cause a seg fault. here's the function def:

```
int search (int bit_type) {                                               // SEARCH FOR A CONSEC NUMBER (of type BIT_TYPE) TO SEE IF ALREADY ENCOUNTERED

    for (int i = 1; i <= MAX[bit_type]; i++) {               //GO THRU ALL ENCOUNTERED CONSEC NUMBERS SO FAR (for type BIT_TYPE)
        if (consec == r[bit_type][i])                           // IF: FOUND
        return i;                                                                       //                      -----> RETURN INDEX OF RECORDED CONSEC_NUM
    }
    // IF: NOT FOUND
    r[bit_type][++MAX[bit_type]] = consec;                          //                      -----> INCREMENT MAX[bit_type]  &  RECORD NEW CONSEC_NUM -------> ARRAY[MAX]
    n[bit_type][MAX[bit_type]] = 1;
    return (MAX[bit_prev]);                                                          //                      -----> RETURN THE NEWLY FILLED INDEX 
}
```

global functions:

```
int MAX[2];
int r[2][200];
int n[2][200];
```

The comments are pretty useless to you guys since you don't have the rest of the program.. but you can just ignore them.

But do you guys see anything I missed?

Comment: Array indexing in C++ starts from `0`.

Comment: `I don't see anything that would cause a seg fault` ... I see 10 things that could cause a seg fault.  Check your indices.

Comment: J...:  which indices? (sounds basically like all of them xD )
Why?? My arrays are all statically allocated.

BatCoder: I know but i want to skip 0 purposely. Must I fill it with something? I mean it technically is filled with something at all times though no? :/

Comment: @Benn, refer [this](http://ideone.com/UgRsjf) please.  It compiled successfully.

Comment: '[here's](http://ideone.com/jEtEQh) the full code.
it does run fine the first few times but then.. segfault

Comment: @Benn It doesn't matter how they are allocated.  If you index them out of bounds then it's fair game for a segfault (at best, since you'll know about the bug right away) or some wacky UB (at worst, since you won't know about the bug right away...)

Comment: define out of bounds for me. i thought it just meant outside the allocated range.

Comment: and i'm not having any problems compiling it. just when running it.

Comment: *"define out of bounds for me"* - If you declare a 3 element array `int arr[3];` the **only** valid indexes are `0`, `1` & `2`.

Comment: yes that was my understanding. my array is allocated for 200 spaces. i'm getting a seg fault when the program starts, ie the array[1] is first being accessed. The program doesn't ever try to go over 200.

Comment: Before each array is indexed, use `assert()` to validate your indexes are within bounds.  You'll likely find your problem immediately.

Answer (score 4):

From the link to your code [here](http://ideone.com/jEtEQh), here is just one error:

```
 int *tmp = new int[MAX[0]];
 for (int y = 0; y <= MAX[0]; y++) {
     tmp[y] = 1;
}
```

You are going out-of-bounds on the last iteration.  You allocated an array with `MAX[0]` items, and on the last iteration you're accessing `tmp[MAX[0]]`.

That loop should be:

```
 int *tmp = new int[MAX[0]];
 for (int y = 0; y < MAX[0]; y++) {
     tmp[y] = 1;
}
```

or better yet:

```
 #include <algorithm>
    //...
    std::fill(tmp, tmp + MAX[0], 1);  // no loop needed
```

or skip the dynamic allocation using `new[]` and use `std::vector`:

```
  #include <vector>
  //...
  std::vector<int> tmp(MAX[0], 1);
```

---

In general, you have multiple loops that do this:

`for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_items_in_array; ++i )`

and then you access your arrays with `array[i]`.  It is the `<=` in that `for` loop condition that is suspicious since it will try to access the array with an out-of-bounds index on the last iteration.

Another example is this:

```
long sum(int arr_r[], int arr_n[], int limit)
{
    long tot = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= limit; i++)
    {
        tot += (arr_r[i])*(arr_n[i]);
    }
    return tot;
}
```

Here, `limit` is the number of elements in the array, and you access `arr_r[i]` on the last iteration, causing undefined behavior.

Arrays are indexed starting from 0 and up to `n - 1`, where `n` is the total number of elements.  Trying to fake 1-based arrays as you're attempting to do almost always results in these types of errors somewhere inside of the code base.